# I can't update the field in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

It is OK in Get, Post, Delete in my laravel code.
But I can't update the field.

### function update in BookController.php

### $data = $this->request->all();

If show the  dd($data), it is null.

What reason?
Help me please.

### BookRequest.php Code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class BookRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'coment' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

### BookController.php Code:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Book;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests\BookRequest;
class BookController extends Controller
{
protected $request;
protected $book;
public function __construct(Request $request, Book $book) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->book = $book;
}
public function update(BookRequest $request, $id) {
    $data = $this->request->all();
    $book = $this->book->find($id);
    $book->name = $data['name'];
    $book->coment = $data['coment'];
    $book->save();
    return response()->json(['status' => Response::HTTP_OK]);
}
}
```

Comment: Why you're using construct for request, you can get request data directly like this:- $request->all();

Answer (score 1):

If i were you i would replace the Controller like below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use App\Book;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Requests\BookRequest;

class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function update(BookRequest $request, $id) {

        $book = Book::find($id);
        $book->update($request->all());
        return response()->json(['status' => Response::HTTP_OK]);
     }
}
```

If you have set up Route:model binding then you can simplify Code more better. Below code only works if you have a Route::model setup in your route file `web.php`.

Check this docs for more details:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

```
public function update(BookRequest $request, Book $book) {
    $book->update($request->all());
    return response()->json(['status' => Response::HTTP_OK]);
 }
```

Comment: Dear Purvesh. Very thanks your kindly. But I can't update the filed. I want to send my source. What is your email?

Comment: Have you setup model class properly?

Comment: Your model file should look something like this.     https://pastebin.com/kzAbjVNr

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$request->all();
```

instead of

```
$this->request->all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved.

My request: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/book
POST , key: _method: PUT

Update Code

```
$data = $request->all();
$book = Boook::find($id);
$book->name = $data['name'];
$book->coment = $data['coment'];
$book->save();
```

Regards.